# kubectl delete all resources except the kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a variant of `kubectl delete all --all` command or some other command to delete all resources except the *kubernetes service*?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a built-in command for it, which means you'll have to script your way out of it, something like this (add an `if` for the namespace you want to spare):

```
$ for ns in $(kubectl get ns --output=jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}); do kubectl delete ns/$ns; done;
```

Note: deleting a namespace deletes all its resources.